# How to center the icons inside a div tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to place the icons in the center of a div.

```
<div class="page_one_footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/moviemanic">
     <i class="fa fa-facebook-official icons" id=""style="font-size: 40px;text-align: center;"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/imVijay4you">
     <i class="fa fa-twitter icons" id="twitter-icon"style="font-size: 40px;text-align: center;"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.icons{
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Why am I not able to place the icons in the center?

Comment: Try `.page_one_footer { text-align: center; }`

Comment: Your CSS is instructing the browser to center-align the text within an element that has the class 'icons'. In other words, you are asking that the text contained in the <i> element be centered within the <i> element, not that the <i> be centered within its container.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `text-align: center` to the container DIV:

```css
.page_one_footer {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page_one_footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/moviemanic">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official icons" id="" style="font-size: 40px;text-align: center;"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/imVijay4you">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter icons" id="twitter-icon" style="font-size: 40px;text-align: center;"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's working.but why I'm unable to if I give .icons which is the class of <a>

Comment: because `a` is an inline element - it doesn't span the whole width, but is aligned left by default. The text-centering is applied to the *content*  of  an element, not to the element itself.

Comment: Thanq very much